# How to use a layout over and over?

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I am building a simple quiz app.A question with four options(radio buttons).
I am using JSON to fetch data.At a time, I only want to show one questions with the four options and on pressing next button the next question will come and  so on until all the question get over.
Till now I am able to show the first question with the options.

On pressing next button how can I show the next question and use the same layout to display the question and options. 
Any help would be great ..

My code to fetch JSON data is below:

```
           public class Main_Activity_For_Quiz extends Activity {

public static int question_number = 0;
JSONObject jsonobject;
JSONArray jsonarray;
String idno = " ";
String url = "";
static ArrayList<String> questionList;
ArrayList<String> opList1;
ArrayList<String> opList2;
ArrayList<String> opList3;
ArrayList<String> opList4;
ArrayList<Integer> idlist;
public RadioGroup radioGroup;


ArrayList<Quiz_MCQ> mcq;
LinearLayout layout, layout2;
// ArrayList<String> nameList, urlList, resList;
TextView textView, textView2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz_mcq);


    String urlid = getIntent().getStringExtra("urlchar");

    url = GlobalVariable.WonderslateQuizURL + urlid;

    Log.e("msg", url);

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Increment the question number for every next click and

            question_number++;
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


            bundle.putExtra("question_number", question_number);


            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            DownloadJSON.PlaceholderFragment fragment = new DownloadJSON.PlaceholderFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.quiz_mcq, "Fragment_question");
            ft.addToBackStack("Fragment_question");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });


    new DownloadJSON().execute();

}


class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        mcq = new ArrayList<Quiz_MCQ>();

        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL(url);
        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                Collections.reverse((List<?>) mcq);

                // if (jsonobject.getString("resType").contains("ps")) {
                //   {
                Quiz_MCQ detailAll = new Quiz_MCQ();

                detailAll.setPs(jsonobject.getString("ps"));
                detailAll.setOp1(jsonobject.getString("op1"));
                detailAll.setOp2(jsonobject.getString("op2"));
                detailAll.setOp3(jsonobject.getString("op3"));
                detailAll.setOp4(jsonobject.getString("op4"));
                detailAll.getId(jsonobject.getInt("id"));


                mcq.add(detailAll);
                Collections.reverse((List<?>) mcq);


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;


    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        //  private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos, container, false);


            TextView txtview = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.question);

            final TextView txtview2 = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChoice);
            RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
            RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
            RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
            RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);


            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            //Get the next question number here
            int position = bundle.getInt("position");
            txtview.setText(questionList.get(position));
            rb1.setText(rb1.get(position));
            rb2.setText(rb2.get(position));
            rb3.setText(rb3.get(position));
            rb4.setText(rb4.get(position));


            return rootView;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why you are using for loop for displaying the data?

Comment: What should I use ?@V V

Comment: Man, where is your button click? Use the button click. Here you are setting all the data to a singe view. So it will replace the previous view

Comment: Button btnnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
            btnnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    aero();
                }
            });
        } I have this but what to do next to move the loop to 2nd position @V V

Comment: rb1.setText(0.getOp1());  rb1.setText(1.getOp1());  rb1.setText(02getOp1());  rb1.setText(3.getOp1()); you just put the value static and run each time. let me know is the options are changing

Comment: No, not getting the others questions @V V

Comment: it will change the first option only

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are tailored for this task. It is easy to use you can learn from the original [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Main idea is to use a container as your main layout. Containers are ViewGroups like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout...So create your main layout and put FrameLayout for the parts you want to use again and again. Then create other fragment layout or layouts to put inside the container.

Comment: Use one fragment only and just pass the data dynamically which is fetched from Json response

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you are using textviews for question and answer.

```
TextView textViewQuestion,textViewOpt1,textViewOpt2,textViewOpt3,textViewOpt4;
```

`int QuestionNo=0;`

now set the data on the views like

```
buttonNext.setOnClickListner(...){
MCQ msq=(MCQ)mcq.get(QuesionNo)
textViewQuestion.setText(msq.getQuestion);
textViewOpt1.setText(msq.getOpt1);
.
.
.
QuestionNo=QuestionNo+1;
}
```

This way, you can do in one activity. for next quiz level downloadJSON.

For first question you can write this code just after the JSON downloaded. just get the MCQ on 0th Position.

Comment: I am trying yours answer lets see @Devender Singh

Comment: yea and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add all question and the answers inside an Arraylist of HashMap type after the selection of each questions. Just update Arraylist like that:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> parent;
HashMap<String,Object> childanswer ;

parent= new ArrayList<>();

childanswer= new HashMap<>();

childanswer.put("key",selectedanswer)
parent.add(childanswer)
```

Also use fragment in same activity and replace view on button click just till all question ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is alright till now. 
In XML declare as below

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/question_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

In your activity ,now then you have saved your questions,all options lists.
Now create a fragment XML file which will have the layout containing

**question_fragment.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout       
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />

   <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

   <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />

   <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New RadioButton"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />

     <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have just created a TextView for Question,4 radio buttons for options and submit button.

Now in you MainActivity use the below code

Declare a variable in global with static keyword

```
    public static int question_number=0;
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Increment the question number for every next click and                   
        send it as argument an receive in the questionfragment and           
        use to index all your array lists.
            question_number++;
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putExtra("question_number",question_number);
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            Questionfragment fragment=new Questionfragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            ft.replace(R.id.question_fragment, ,"Fragment_question");
            ft.addToBackStack("Fragment_question");
            ft.commit();
        }
         });


       Now copy this new fragment code in MainActivity below main   
    function

      public static class Questionfragment extends Fragment {
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup      
      container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_fragment, 
      container, false);

       TextView textview=findViewById(R.id.textview);
       RadioButton radioButton1=findViewById(radioButton1);
        RadioButton radioButton2=findViewById(radioButton2);
       RadioButton radioButton3=findViewById(radioButton3);
        RadioButton radioButton4=findViewById(radioButton4);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        //Get the next question number here
        int position = bundle.getInt("position");
       textview.setText(questionList.get(position));
       radioButton1.setText(rb1.get(position));
       radioButton2.setText(rb2.get(position));
       radioButton3.setText(rb3.get(position));
       radioButton4.setText(rb4.get(position));

        return view;
    }

   }
```

Comment: Where to put the first half of the code @Sairam Rachapudi

Comment: Put the first half inside the main function and rest outside the main function.

Comment: Getting a lots of error but thanks @Sairam Rachapudi

Comment: Actually I sent the pseduo code .. Edit the code in your terms. But the main concept is creating a fragment. Use fragment manager to replace the views and send the argument to tell which question number it should represent.
Which errors are you getting ?

Comment: Declare the arraylists in global and static.
onbuttonclick call the asynctask...In do-in-background function .. put the fragment transaction code and run. It will work for sure